# Not able to install XFire plugin in eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, xfire

I am trying to install XFire plugin in eclipse Luna, but it is throwing the below error
"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: XFire IDE 1.0.2.xfire125 (org.codehaus.xfire.eclipse.feature.group 1.0.2.xfire125)
  Missing requirement: XFire IDE 1.0.2.xfire125 (org.codehaus.xfire.eclipse.feature.group 1.0.2.xfire125) requires 'org.eclipse.update.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found"

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an old plugin that requires the `org.eclipse.update.core` plugin which is only in Eclipse 3.x.

So unless you can find a newer version (or build the code from the source) this is not compatible with Eclipse Luna.

Comment: yes, it is old plugin. i tried to generate the code from the eclipse itself. But now my service is not able to invoke the other webservice, it is throwing "Class doesnt have webservice annotations". Since i generated using webservice client from eclipse. Can you please help me on this, if you dont mind that i am deviating from the original problem?

Comment: I don't know anything about web services.

Comment: i could see your tags has webservices. Ok no problem. Thank you.